# Rails HABTM association: record not inserting into joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have to model `User` and `Company`.
And association like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

and

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

In migration to create joining table:

```
class CreateCompaniesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :companies_users, :id => false do |t|
     t.references :company
     t.references :user

     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

**It's working fine, when:**

```
user = User.new(:name => "name", :email => "email@em.com" :password => "pass")
user.companies.find_or_create_by_name(:name => "name")

user.save
```

**It's not working, (but inserting data into `users` and `companies`) when:**

```
user = User.first # or by finding some existing user
user.companies.find_or_create_by_name(:name => "name")
```

Additionally it's showing a message:

```
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Company.page.
```

Please help me to get out of this. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you used wrong method, try `user.companies.find_or_create_by(:name => "name")`, do you want to find/create new company belongs to user with name of company is `name` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Kaminari for pagination? Please see this issue: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/48

There are a number of issues of this sort that were opened against Kaminari over the years, including one based on using will_paginate alongside it. All of these issues result in that "Creating scope :page" message you're seeing.

Try removing Kaminari from your gemfile/bundle and then retrying your test case.

Alternately, try inspecting the new company you've created in user.companies and make sure it's valid. The find_or_create will not save if the newly created object is failing validations.